# AAD hosted Blazor Webassembly - How to get subset of user's AD groups when user is member of large number of groups

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, blazor-client-side

I have asked this [question](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22197) on ASP.Net Core github repo, but I do not think my query was sufficiently answered, so posting the question here.

I followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/azure-active-directory-groups-and-roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to get a user's AD groups as claims. However, the user is member of a large number of groups, and I just see a single claim "hasGroups".

My question is: what is the suggested best practice/pattern to follow in such cases, as I am interested in retrieving only a few of the user's groups that match a string pattern. Where would I even write the code to perform this filter?

I know how to code the graph api query, but where/when exactly to make this call is unclear. And once I retrieve the groups from Graph Api, how do I reflect the group information into the token claims, so the client app can use regular Authorization mechanism, without knowing the details of how the user's groups were populated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the recommended way of doing it, but the docs here talk about adding groups and roles to use the user object claims for blazor. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/azure-active-directory-groups-and-roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1

I'm not sure if it's even possible, but in the customuserfactory, I would try to replace the

```
   foreach (var group in account.Groups)
    {
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("group", group));
    }
```

with some code to try to call the graph api (somehow get the token to call the api with, that's the part I'm not sure on), parse the groups and add them to the user claims, 
then follow the rest of the example of how to incorporate that into the [authorize] mechanism.

again, I'm not super familiar with blazor wasm yet, and I couldn't find any docs other than this to add groups/roles into the authorization mechanism. 
if anyone else has a better method of doing it or why this wouldn't work feel free to chime in, but I hope that this can at least give you some ideas and is slightly useful.